# Changing color of the console outputs in Pycharm

Tags: pytorch, pycharm, settings, yolov8

I know it is a bit weird question but, I was wondering if it is possible to change the colors of output text such as progress bars and percentages displaying during the machine learning model training in Pycharm?[image: as you can see right part of the image]

For some reason this red text kind of bothering me since it has some resemblance with errors

In settings I can see that we can change the colors of background, error output, standard output, system output, user input but those are not the ones I am looking for.

Anyone has any idea?

Looked online for similar questions. Also checked the documentation